# IPTables: restrict outgoing protocols for specific ip range

Tags: iptables

Regarding the OUTPUT chain: I want to have a default policy of ACCEPT, but for a specific destination CIDR, I want to allow outgoing connections only via SSH. Incoming traffic from that CIDR must remain unrestricted. Currently the OUTPUT chain has no restrictions at all.

I'm thinking this:

```
iptables -F OUTPUT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -d myCIDR --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -d myCIDR -m state --state NEW -j REJECT
```

Am I close?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear. Do you want to allow only SSH connections?

If so, you can use these rules:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s cidr_here --dport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

You have written the 22nd port to the OUTPUT chain with --dport (destination port). It is not a destination port in this case. It should be a source port.

Comment: Actually I think my question is quite clear, I only want to allow ssh connections from that server to that CIDR. Connections to that CIDR over other tcp ports must be blocked. Regarding the port, when one initiates an ssh connection it's the destination port that is 22, isn't it? Look at example #8 in this link: https://crm.vpscheap.net/index.php?rp=/knowledgebase/29/25-Most-Frequently-Used-Linux-IPTables-Rules-Examples.html

Comment: Sorry, I understood what you meant now. There is a website. It is portquiz.net. I used its IP address for testing purpose.
I used these 2 IPtables rules:

`iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -d 52.47.209.216/32 --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT` and 
`iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -d 52.47.209.216/32 -m state --state NEW -j REJECT`

This command is working fine: `nc -v 52.47.209.216 22`
This command is not working (as expected): `nc -v 52.47.209.216 80`

Do you have another rule in the NAT chain? You can check it with: iptables -vnL -t nat

Comment: Yes, there is a problem with the rejecting part, and I can't spot it.

Comment: Actually I take that back, I tried it on a test server of my own and it seems to work. I can ssh to the specific CIDR, but I can't connect to port 80 or any other non-22 port.